# Set default value on select of page layout in cms_page_form.xml

Tags: xml, content-management-system, magento2

I would like to set a default value for the select on the page layout when creating a new cms page in magento 2. unfortunately             `<item name="default" xsi:type="string">2</item>` to set the second item in the list as default, isn't working. Any thoughts on how to do this in xml?

```
<field name="page_layout">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="options" xsi:type="object">Magento\Cms\Model\Page\Source\PageLayout</item>
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Layout</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">select</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">page_layout</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```